# Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidAgrumentException: the uri is invalid

Tags: 8

I am getting an error related The URI '/photo-gallery' is invalid. You must use a valid URI scheme at /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Url.php line 280

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `internal` scheme to make a valid URI from an internal route. e.g.

```
internal:/photo-gallery
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you plz tell me on which file i can use this ? Bcoz am not a developer

Comment: I couldn't know, sorry. Wherever you're using `/photo-gallery` you need to be using `internal:/photo-gallery` instead, that's as much as I can say without access to the site

Comment: Actually am moving the site on server and its shows "The website encountered an unexpected error" and when i open the error log its show the valid uri error. I have searched all the files related /photo-gallery but there is no hard coded. Is this possible it is in database?

Comment: Yes that's likely

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error if you are providing a URL to a Link field that is external but not providing an http/https:// value, like this:

"www.google.com/foo/bar"

The field validation will prevent this from being entered, but if you are doing content migrations or any scripted imports they can still get in.

Comment: Do you know how to bypass this?